# Rails Dev Environment on Windows 10 :: NameError & GemRequire errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, development-environment

I am installing a new Windows 10 environment to continue developing an already-existing Rails API. After `bundle install`, I need to setup the db. Here's the command I am running, and the output with the errors. I am not a Rails developer, and simply need to run this API to start hacking on the Client JavaScript. Where should I start looking to fix this?

`$ rake db:setup --trace`

```
rake aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'responders'.
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
C:/msys64/home/Isaac Lewis/vibragenix-api/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
C:/msys64/home/Isaac Lewis/vibragenix-api/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
NameError: uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelHelper
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:40:in `<module:Helpers>'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/view_paths.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/base.rb:204:in `<class:Base>'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/base.rb:164:in `<module:ActionController>'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/responders-2.1.0/lib/responders/controller_method.rb:37:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/responders-2.1.0/lib/responders.rb:15:in `<module:Responders>'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/responders-2.1.0/lib/responders.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `require'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in require'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
C:/msys64/home/Isaac Lewis/vibragenix-api/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
C:/msys64/home/Isaac Lewis/vibragenix-api/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
```

Comment: This may be nothing, but paths with spaces in them have caused much pain historically with rails..  I notice your path has your name with a space.. https://gist.github.com/KelseyDH/11198922

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the gem 'responders' isn't installed correctly. Try running 'gem list' and see if you've got it installed. If it's not, then try running 'gem install responders' and try again.

P.S. I wanted to comment (not answer) but I don't have the required reputation yet.

P.P.S. I've also had issues in the past with certain gems and the x64 version of ruby so perhaps it could also be down to that. Apologies that this response is rather vague.